# How to prove the set of integers under addition and multiplication modulo n is a commutative ring with unity 1?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How to prove the set of integers under addition and  multiplication modulo n is a commutative ring with unity 1?

Comment: Context? What’s your knowledge about rings, background, what exactly are you finding difficult about this problem? Simple problem statements such as this aren’t well-received on MSE 

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Why? It is a clear question.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the clarity of the question. It has to do with our community standards, which you presumably agreed to when you registered.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs These standards are formed by the community, I am part of it, and strongly disagree it. Furthermore, I would be surprised if such a "standard" would have a *real* acceptance in the community.

Comment: Hey, I’m just the messenger, reporting what I see every single day on this site.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs It is a new "rule" invented by some [deletionist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deletionism_and_inclusionism_in_Wikipedia) community members, it hadn't even supported by the wide community.

Comment: I don't know what's new about it. I've been here since 2013, and it's always been a thing. It seems to enjoy widespread support, from the conversations I see in Meta about it. Why not start a thread there, and ask?

Comment: More relevant to the current context, you've now put about three times as much energy into arguing about this than it would have taken you to just provide context, which leads to better, more helpful answers anyway. What's your priority here?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs It is not my question. I am arguing that the "context" is irrelevant in this case, the problem is clear, the user asks for a trivial proof. Closing the question saying that "it is trivial, google for that", I would say it is okay. Closing the question as wanting "context" is imho surreal and harmful.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Btw, my goal was with my improvements to save the content, at least as a closed question.

Comment: @peterh, I didn't realize it wasn't your question, sorry. I agree that no-context closes are weird, but I've come to accept that it's how this site works. In my experience, it's not a handful of "deletionists", but really is the prevailing culture of the site. Choosing my battles in life, I've decided to let this one slide. In general, I do agree with certain of the arguments: telling us your level of understanding leads to better, more helpful answers.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs No prob. I am happy to understand your goals. There is also a practical argument, check [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/886058/trajectory-of-accepted-and-rejected-questions-by-month?Smooth=6#graph).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

A commutative ring with unity one has following properties:

- closure of addition and multiplication
- associativity of addition and multiplication
- commutativity of addition and multiplication
- unity zero for addition and unity 1 for multiplication
- inverse elements wrt addition
- left and right distributivity of the multiplication wrt the addition.

Try to prove all these properties for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$.